# FFMPEG command to mix audio and video with adjustable volume, plays till Video length and loop audio entire video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, android

I have:

1. Video file of X length
2. Audio of Y length

I am trying to achieve an output video that has the following qualities:

1. The volume level of the added audio should be adjustable
2. The audio should loop till the end of the video
3. It should not break even if the input video does not have any audio
4. I should be able to mute the audio of the source video if needed.
5. All of the above, in the fastest possible way.

I'm not well versed with FFMPEG, maybe some experts could help.